# difference in two tables Syntax error in SQL FROM Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to compare two tables with different columns.

I tried below code but it is giving syntax error

Syntax error:
"Exception thrown by code stage: Syntax error in FROM clause"

```
SELECT [Sheet1].[ID], [Sheet2].[ID_EXT] from [Sheet1], [Sheet2]
A As (SELECT [Sheet1].[ID], ([Sheet1].[Email] + ';' + [Sheet2].[Long Email]) as email from [Sheet1] inner join [Sheet2] 
on [Sheet1].[ID] = FORMAT([Sheet2].[ID_EXT],'00000000000')  
WHERE [Sheet2].[Type] = 3 AND UCase [Sheet1].[Email] <> UCase [Sheet2].[Long Email]) 
B As (SELECT [Sheet1].[ID], ([Sheet1].[Batchcode] + ';' + str([Sheet2].[Code])) as Code from [Sheet1] inner join [Sheet2] on [Sheet1].[ID] = FORMAT([Sheet2].[ID_EXT],'00000000000') WHERE [Sheet2].[Type]= 3 AND [Sheet1].[Batchcode]<>FORMAT([Sheet2].[Code],'0000))
SELECT [A].[ID], [A].[Email], [B].[Batchcode] from [A] Full outer join [A] ON [A].[ID]=[B].[ID_EXT]
```

Comment: *it is giving syntax error* isn't useful as a problem description. What is that syntax error? What is the exact error message you're seeing? It's on the screen right in front of you, but we can't see your screen from where we're sitting. You're asking us for free help, so it's in your best interest to give us the details you already have that will make it easier for us to help you. Please [edit] your post and provide the *exact, complete error message*.

Comment: If your question is about a syntax error and it doesn't include the error message something has gone wrong. A question should also include the tables' definition (as `CREATE TABLE` statements), sample data (as `INSERT INTO`) statements, and the desired result with that sample data.

Comment: 1. you should have added a better formatted sql in description (which is more readable)
2. You should have added the error text as well.

Comment: I am excepting output look like below example:
Shee1:
ID                  Email        Batchcode
00000002547     test@gmail.com      0809
00000002647     test1@gmail.com     7852
00000007645     test2@gmail.com     3698
00000001045     test3@gmail.com     7855
Sheet2:
ID_EXT            Type      LongEmail          Code
2547               3       test2@gmail.com     0809
2647               3       test1@gmail.com     7852
Output:
ID                       Email                                   Code
2547         test@gmail.com;test2@gmail.com

Comment: @Ken--Thanks your time... I am sorry I forgot to mention error message. Yes I am asking free help because I don't have that much coding experience.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of A as (select...) you need , (select ... ) as A.